# Find value in dictionary of type <string, string[]>

Tags: c#, dictionary

Here is the code I already have, which works:

```
private string GetRegionByStore(string store)
{
    foreach (string items in d.Keys)
    {
        if (d[items].Contains(store))
        {
            return items;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This searches for a key in a dictionary like this:

```
d.Add("4Q", new string[] { "27", "49", "198", "214", "226", "347", "351", "361", "439", "449", "613", "657", "662", "685" });
```

There are many entries like 4Q, 4Z, 4J and so on, and each have a `string[]` with numbers inside. There will never be the same number in another entry, so no worry of duplicates.

The method I am using now currently works, but it feels very hacky and like it is bad practice. Is there a LINQ query I can do to achieve the same thing?

To summarize: Find a number within each dictionary(?), and if it exists, return the key.

Comment: I don't think this is hacky at all. I think this code is very straightforward, easy to read and easy to understand. I am not sure that a LINQ query (which probably exists) will be as easy to read/understand as your code here is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
  var strores = d.Where(e => e.Value.Contains("27")).Select(e => e.Key).ToList();
```

The above will return a list of `Key`s from your `Dictionary<string, string[]>` collection where the `Value` of the collection is found to contain the string you have searched for.

Answer (score 3):

> You can use this version code:

```
private string GetRegionByStore(string store)
{
     d.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => d[k].Contains(store));
}
```

> To find all keys in dictionary:

```
private string GetRegionByStore(string store)
{
     d.Keys.Where(k => d[k].Contains(store)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: >FirstOrDefault method return the first key where their colecction contains a value of a variable _store_,if there not exist any key return null, becase is a default value of string type.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq:

```
d.Single(x => x.Value.Contains("198")).Key // would return "4Q" in your example
```